# Github not deploying the files correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

I followed a tutorial to deploy a React app to github pages. When I deploy, I get no error messages, but when I check the URL, I just see a blank page, i used parcel to bundle the app and i am commiting the DIST file (see https://the717q.github.io/my-react-app/).

It runs locally fine using "npm start". Whenever I deploy I just run "npm run deploy".

My repository is here: https://github.com/the717q/my-react-app

I already tried everything but i am not being able to fix this.
Here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "projetoreact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": false,
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.7.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel ./public/index.html",
    "build": "parcel ./public/index.html",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d dist"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you notice that your `start` and `build` scripts are identical? Github pages is not going to run your dev server to serve your React app. You have to actually build the project.

Comment: If you are new to react and especially if you are new to programming period start with something like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) instead of trying to set up all the parts yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [code in your repository](https://github.com/the717q/my-react-app/blob/master/index.html), the comments have explained well what happens:

```
<!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that comment in the HTML is misleading: it appears to be from a create-react-app application, and OP doesn't appear to actually be using create-react-app.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes you are right. As this comment is there from the beginning of the react application. The main problem is that his `css` & `js` files are not loading properly. As it is returning a **404** error because of the wrong URL configuration as I described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352088/14359374

Answer (score 1):

I can see your code is right. If you just check your browser console you will find the required information.
[image]

So it looks like you are hosting the site on a path instead of hosting it directly on a root domain. So, you need to update your project's build code if you want to host it on that path.

Your react app is looking for the files in the root domain for example it is looking for the file `index.995846b2.js` in this path `https://the717q.github.io/index.995846b2.js` but it should be looking for it in this path `https://the717q.github.io/my-react-app/index.995846b2.js`

So there is 2 way to fix it.

1. Use a direct domain with the repository and don't host it on a path, host it directly on `example.github.io`

***OR***

2. Update your index.html file by removing `/` from the assets URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My first React Project</title>

    <!-- JavaScript Source File -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.36a57046.css" />
    <script src="index.995846b2.js" type="module" defer=""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: You can also use `/my-react-app/` instead of removing `/`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My first React Project</title>

    <!-- JavaScript Source File -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my-react-app/index.36a57046.css" />
    <script src="/my-react-app/index.995846b2.js" type="module" defer=""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `npm run build` is going to run the build script in package.json... which in this case appears to be identical to `npm start`. There's no indication that the OP is using react-scripts (e.g. in create-react-app)

Comment: @JaredSmith I've updated my answer please check.

Comment: @jaredSmith i noticied it and i fixed it... Thank you !

Comment: @udoyhasan been searching for a solution since yesterday.

Comment: @udoyhasan I'm not the OP, so I can't accept your answer. I did upvote your answer though.

Comment: Sorry, @JaredSmith I accidentally mentioned you. I was mentioning André Silveira.

Comment: @AndréSilveira I can see you have followed this answer to fix your problem so please mark this answer as the solution. If you mark the right answer as a solution then others will be also benefited from this answer. Thank you.